# How to destroy an object in java without a name?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am looping through an array and based on the values creating a different object. and I want to know how would you delete or de-reference an object with no name.

Here's an example of what I mean

```
new Test(); // so now how would I delete this instance of test?
```

Comment: In Java, unlike C/C++, the JVM handles garbage collection for you.  You don't need to call `delete` or anything like that.

Comment: You should review a basic tutorial of how Java works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new Test().m1().m2();
// here the previous instance may be deleted, there is no reference to `new Test()`
```

It will be deleted by the GC *after* (we don't know exactly when it will be called) all operations (`m1`, `m2` methods in our example) over it are done.

You could call `Runtime.getRuntime().gc()` (or simply [`System.gc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc())), but there is no guarantee that the garbage collector will come.

I tried to draw how I can imagine it.

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing in java. In Java garbage collection is automated we do not have control over it.

Comment: We cannot _force_ the JVM to garbage collect (not without a massive hack), but we _can_ politely ask it to using `System.gc()`.

Answer (score 1):

Java performs GC by itself, no need to do it manually.

Mentioned Object should be not be in use to be eligible for GC. JVM will do multiple scans and will move these objects from one generation to another to determine the eligibility of GC and frees the memory when the objects are not reachable.

Answer (score 1):

Java will automatically delete them, it is called Garbage Collecting ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the object is a local variable it will automatically get garbage collected when ever the garbage collection occurs.